# How to retain the index position back to the ouput when/after running pandas iterrorws?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

In the following pandas dataframe:

```
d1 = pd.read_csv('to_count.mcve.txt', sep='\t')
d1 = d1.set_index(['pos'], append=True)

       M1           M2       F1   F2
  pos                        
0 23   A,B,A,C,D    A,C,B    A    D
1 24   A,B,B,C,B    A,B,A    B    B
2 28   C,B,C,D,E    B,C      E    C
```

I used the below code to do some counting:

```
hapX_count = pd.DataFrame()
hapY_count = pd.DataFrame()
for index, lines in d1.iterrows():
    hap_x = lines['F1']
    hap_y = lines['F2']
    x_count = lines.apply(lambda x: x.count(hap_x)/2 if len(x) > 5 else x.count(hap_x))
    y_count = lines.apply(lambda x: x.count(hap_y)/2 if len(x) > 5 else x.count(hap_y))

    hapX_count = hapX_count.append(x_count)
    hapY_count = hapY_count.append(y_count)


print(hapX_count)
```

Output is:

```
         F1   F2   M1   M2
(0, 23)  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
(1, 24)  1.0  1.0  1.5  1.0
(2, 28)  1.0  0.0  0.5  0.0
```

**How can I get the index value (`pos`) back as they were in the previous data?** I can use the index to call the position of those tuple. But, I want to automate the process so all the indexes are retained, because there will be more than one index (not just `pos`) in my original data.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the two lines above your for loop with the below lines. This will create empty DataFrames with the index having the same names as the index of `d1`.

```
hapX_count = pd.DataFrame(index=d1.index[0:0])
hapY_count = pd.DataFrame(index=d1.index[0:0])
```